# Angular ag-grid-angular get rid of cell paddings

Tags: css, angular, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid-angular

and just can't get rid of cells top and bottom inner padding

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethign like this might help you. But the important thing is that the change should be made where you have your imports of the ag grid. this I'm changing them from 40px height to 30px height and also the line height

```
  @import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

.ag-theme-alpine .ag-row {
  height: 30px;
}
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell, .ag-theme-alpine .ag-full-width-row .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group{
  line-height: min(var(--ag-row-height, 30px), 30px);
}
```

here is an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-k3cp9p?file=src/styles.scss

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried your solution and put 10px whrever you put  30px
and it seems like the text moved up but the line didn't get smaller and the padding inside didnt dissaper.

Comment: Are you trying it on your code or the stackblitz code? @Erez You can also try this `.ag-theme-alpine .ag-row {
  height: 20px;
}
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell,
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-full-width-row .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group {
  line-height: 20px;
}` with 10px the font size seems to be a bit bigger so changes seems not to change the padding <https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-k3cp9p?file=src/styles.scss>

Comment: For angular component you should add also ::ng-deep. `::ng-deep .ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell, .ag-theme-alpine .ag-full-width-row .ag-cell-wrapper.ag-row-group {
    line-height: min(var(--ag-row-height, 25px), 25px);
}`